# Can anyone explain these command lines from GitHub "git tutorial"?

Tags: git

Every time you create a new repository on GitHub, it shows you these command lines that I've always found useful...

```
echo "# Project" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M master
git remote add origin https://github.com/Username/Project.git
git push -u origin master
```

But I have no idea what they really do... Can anyone help this poor Git newbie?

Comment: How about reading Git's documentation? https://git-scm.com/docs

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if I had gotten a clear answer from the Git documentation...

Comment: @mrodo: Git documentation can be pretty impenetrable. Still, to the OP: this isn't really a good StackOverflow question. You're perhaps best sent to a good book or tutorial. The best one I can recommend today is [the Pro Git 2 book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), which is free at the link here.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "# Project" >> README.md
```

This creates a README in your current directory

```
git init
```

This will create a new .git directory to store commits and other objects.

```
git add README.md
```

Before adding a file to the repository, it must first be staged.

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

This would commit our staged changes into the repository.

```
git branch -M master
```

With a -m or -M option, oldbranch will be renamed to newbranch. If oldbranch had a corresponding reflog, it is renamed to match newbranch, and a reflog entry is created to remember the branch renaming. If newbranch exists, -M must be used to force the rename to happen

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/Username/Project.git
```

This would add a remote url to an existing git repository

```
git push -u origin master
```

Push - moves/uploads the local changes (or snapshot) to the remote GitLab repository

Useful links:
https://learngitbranching.js.org/
https://doane-ccla.gitbook.io/docs/git-version-control/git-basics